After upgrade 22.04.5 LTS to 24.04.1 LTS terminal won't start
I upgraded on a Dell Inspiron 3847 and everything completed OK (wm starts ok, thunderbird, firefox looks ok).
However, I can't get terminal to start/display. No terminal precludes any fixes.
I can ssh from another computer fine, so if I can find the solution there is a way to get things going.

From terminal icon on dock - indicates started, but no display
From gnome-termial (via ssh) "Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display) Maybe understandable for ssh termial.
From "settings:apps:terminal:open" get same response (also msg "not sandboxed")

All these get same syslog entry, but I don't know how to proceed/fix.
2024-11-04T12:32:28.721069-08:00 glen-Inspiron-3847 systemd[2429]: Started app-gnome-org.gnome.Terminal-26087.scope - Application launched by gnome-shell.
2024-11-04T12:32:28.901828-08:00 glen-Inspiron-3847 dbus-daemon[2514]: [session uid=1000 pid=2514] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.285' (uid=1000 pid=26091 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real" label="unconfined")
2024-11-04T12:32:28.914971-08:00 glen-Inspiron-3847 systemd[2429]: Starting gnome-terminal-server.service - GNOME Terminal Server...
2024-11-04T12:32:29.196141-08:00 glen-Inspiron-3847 dbus-daemon[2514]: [session uid=1000 pid=2514] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
2024-11-04T12:32:29.196409-08:00 glen-Inspiron-3847 systemd[2429]: Started gnome-terminal-server.service - GNOME Terminal Server.
2024-11-04T12:32:29.267052-08:00 glen-Inspiron-3847 gnome-shell[2705]: meta_window_set_stack_position_no_sync: assertion 'window->stack_position >= 0' failed
2024-11-04T12:32:29.276262-08:00 glen-Inspiron-3847 systemd[2429]: Started vte-spawn-99ba643f-b795-4446-ad7b-c9a4a1d2525e.scope - VTE child process 26104 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 26097.

Pointers/solutions?
Thanks

Welcome to ASK. Try CTL-ALT F3 (F4, F5 etc) to give you a terminal and CTL-ATL F1 to go back to the Gnome Display Manager (gdm). I think CTL-ALT F2 goes to a new login screen.
